# How to integrate a MQTT broker into Linux based raspbian kernel source code and cross compile in Ubuntu 20.04.2?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

I’m trying to integrate a MQTT broker into Linux based raspbian kernel source code, which I cloned from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.4.y. I need to integrate the mqtt broker and cross-compile the same for Raspberry Pi 3. Im using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS for cross compiling the code.
I was able to successfully cross-compile the cloned code in  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS by following steps in  https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md. And, I was able to flash the generated kernel image and install libraries onto raspberry pi. Now as I have already mentioned, I’m looking for some guidance to integrate mqtt broker onto the same source code and re-compile same.

Any kind of supports will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You don't, a MQTT broker has no place being part of the kernel. Also asking for instructions/tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow. Are you are looking to build an entire OS from scratch or just a custom kernel to add specific support for something?

Comment: I can see the the mqtt mosquitto broker code here: [https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/debian](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/debian). But I'm looking for steps to integrate this with RPi kernel code in [https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.4.y](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.4.y) and recompile same

Comment: As I said you Do Not integrate a broker into a kernel. A broker is a user space application. If you are trying to build a whole OS from scratch I suggest you look at Yocto which hard a full build system

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66775378/edit) the question to explain the larger problem you are actually trying to solve here. Why do you want to build everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use install python MQTT broker (mosquitto) or crosscompile paho broker and run on raspberry

Comment: I can see the the mqtt mosquitto broker code here: [https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/debian](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/tree/debian)  .But I'm looking for steps to integrate this with RPi kernel code in [https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.4.y](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-5.4.y) and recompile same.